# Angular Ng-Repeat with Key Value list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am returning an object that contains key/value that needs to be iterated through.
I am doing it like this:

```
ng-repeat="(index, thing) in data"
```

Pretty simple, however I am needing to limit it to 2 items. and the regular limitTo Angular filter doesn't seem to work this way. Is it possible to filter this way in the view? or will i have to modify the data before it reaches the view? For example, i'd like to be able to do this:

```
ng-repeat="(index, thing) in data | limitTo:2"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own filter called something like `limitObjecTo` that is capable of returning an object with only the first two properties.

Is there some reason you're not using an array?  It seems much more appropriate for this.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LgTfs/

```
.filter('limitObjectTo', function() {
  return function(obj, limit) {
    var newObj = {}, i = 0, p;
    for (p in obj) {
      newObj[p] = obj[p];
      if (++i === limit) break;
    }
    return newObj;
  };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have many decisions of how the API is built.

Comment: If you do not control the API, you can still convert your data to a regular array in Javascript. This will make it much easier to use filters like limitTo.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Langdon for your solution! I made some improvements, in order to limit FROM and limit TO:

```
.filter('limitObjectFromTo', function() {
      return function(obj, limitFrom, limitTo) {
         var newObj = {},
          i = 0;
          for (var p in obj) {
            if (i >= limitFrom) newObj[p] = obj[p];
            if (++i === limitTo) break;
          }
        return newObj;
      };
  });
```

Maybe someone will use it :-) Then you just add: `| limitObjectFromTo: 2:6` to limit from 2 to 6.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use `$index` in combination with `ng-if` to filter the keys as below

```
   fruVeg = {
                'a' : 'apple',
                'b' : 'banana',
                'c' : 'carrot',
                'd' : 'fandelion',
                'e' : 'eggs',
                'f': 'fig'
            };
```

On my template, i did this to limit it to the top 4 keys in the funcs object

```
<label ng-repeat='(key,val) in fruVeg' ng-if="$index<4"> [[key]]</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case i just add track by and it worked

```html
<tr ng-repeat="(key,preview) in clients.mobiles | limitTo:5 track by $index">
  <td>{{preview}}</td>
  <td>{{clients.text[key]['textClean']}}</td>
</tr>
```